# How do I from variables to growth rates of variables, approximately?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm given a function of the form: $$ y = x + 2 $$

I'm asked to derive the relationship between the growth rate of $ y $ to the growth rate of $ x $, approximately. I'm also given this example without derivation: If $ z = x^a $, then $ g_z = a \ g_x $, where $ g_z $ and $ g_x $ are the growth rates of $ z $ and $ x $ respectively.

How do I derive the relationship? I can see that $ y = x + 2 $ is very similar to $ z = x^a $, if we have $ a = 1 $ and add in a constant term. Without the constant term, the growth rate of $ x $ and $ y $ would be equal to each other. How do I handle the constant term?

Comment: Let $2=2x^0$ and continue with your formula

Comment: I have some doubts, regarding the relations $z=x^a \rightarrow g_z = a g_x$. Shouldn't it be $g_z = a x^{a-1} g_x$?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you mean. Usually the growth rate (for $x\rightarrow \infty$) is described with the so-called Landau-symbol $O(f(x))$ In this case we have $x+2=O(x)$ because of $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x+2}{x}=1$$ This means that the growth rates of $x$ and $x+2$ coincide. It is not necessary that the values are actually equal at some point.